# Accessing ViewModelFactory / httpclient / apicommands from WPF control's events page

Tags: c#, wpf

So I recently got wpf to api/server uploads working, and now Im on the reverse path of getting downloads (server to wpf) working.
How can I access my client's library commands from the c# events page behind the Xaml mark up View? Im getting crashing if I alter the constructor, and object reference not set to an instance of an object errors with or without a second constructor.  The commented out code is several things that I've tried.

I get the System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error with this command:

var response = _invoiceDownloadCommand.DownloadAsync(filename);

```
 public partial class InvoicesView
{
  //  private ApiDownloadCommand<DisplayableInvoice> _invoiceDownloadCommand;
    private DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory _invoiceDownloadCommand;
   // private InvoiceViewModel _invoiceViewModel;
    public InvoicesView()
    {
      //  _invoiceDownloadCommand = new() DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory;
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        InitializeComponent();
        var kek = new DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory(ApiDownloadCommand<DisplayableInvoice> _invoiceDownloadCommand);
       // _invoiceDownloadCommand = new(DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory);
    }      
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadCommand?.Execute(null);
        
       // DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory invoiceDownloadCommand = DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory;
    }

    //private interface IViewFactory
    //{
    //    DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory Kek<DisplayableInvoice>();
    //    DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory Kek<TInput, DisplayableInvoice>(TInput input);
    //}
    //public InvoicesView(DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory invoiceDownloadCommand)
    //{
    //    invoiceDownloadCommand = _invoiceDownloadCommand;
    //}
private void Downloader(string filename)
    {
        if (filename == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File Must Be Listed");
           // return;
        }
        var response = _invoiceDownloadCommand.DownloadAsync(filename);
        MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());    
    }
```

[image: Program Layout]

Comment: what is DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory? You write IViewFactory, but you dont implement it. You dont know C#. `var kek = new DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory(ApiDownloadCommand<DisplayableInvoice> _invoiceDownloadCommand);` - it's not valid code `_invoiceDownloadCommand = new(DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory);` - I think it's not valid too. It should be, for example `var factory = new DownloadInvoiceViewModelFactory(); _invoiceDownloadCommand = new Command(factory.Create);`

Comment: Usually, ViewModelFactory should create ViewModel for View.  command should call you target method

Comment: the IviewFactory is nothing,  it was like the 5th attempt, and really just checking out the interface

Comment: Where  exactly are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a download confirmation screen View where I could then pass my file download arguments with the dialog confirmation, whereas I was trying to make 2 separate calls on the same model. This allowed for easy file transfer back up the model.